# why the char pointer will be automatically cleared?

Tags: c, pointers

Here's my code:

```
tmpip = get_public_ip();
pubip = strtok(tmpip, "\n");
sprintf(buffer, "220 FTPUtils Server [%s]", pubip);
len_string = strlen(buffer)+1;
if(send(newsockd, &len_string, sizeof(len_string), 0) < 0){
    perror("Errore invio len buffer");
    onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
}
if(send(newsockd, buffer, len_string, 0) < 0){
    perror("Errore durante l'invio");
    onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
}
pubip = NULL;
free(tmpip);
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));


if(recv(newsockd, &len_string, sizeof(len_string), MSG_WAITALL) < 0){
    perror("Errore ricezione len user buffer");
    onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
}
if(recv(newsockd, buffer, len_string, 0) < 0){
    perror("Errore ricezione del nome utente");
    onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
}       
user_string = strtok(buffer, " ");
username = strtok(NULL, "\n");
fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", user_string, username);
sprintf(saved_user, "%s", username);
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

if(recv(newsockd, &len_string, sizeof(len_string), MSG_WAITALL) < 0){
    perror("Errore ricezione len pass buffer");
    onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
}
if(recv(newsockd, buffer, len_string, 0) < 0){
    perror("Errore ricezione password");
    onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
}
pass_string = strtok(buffer, " ");
password = strtok(NULL, "\n");
fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", pass_string, password);
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

printf("%s %s\n", username, password);
```

I have a problem with the last debug `printf`: it prints to stdout **nothing**!!
Why are my pointer (username and password) cleared???
It is strange because the 2 `fprintf` works perfectly but the last `printf` no...

Comment: Because `memset` zeroed out the entire `buffer`, and both `username` and `password` point into particular bytes inside `buffer`.

Comment: You're right XD wake up polslinux wake up :D

Comment: error in this? printf("%s %s\n", username, password);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the `username` and the `password` **point to locations inside `buffer`**. That's how `strtok` works.

In other words, when you zero the buffer using `memset` you're zeroing out the memory to which `username` and `password` point. A simple workaround would be to duplicate that memory:

```
username = strtok(NULL, "\n");
username = strdup(username);
```

Note `strdup` isn't standard but quite easy to implement using `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't thought to strdup!!

Comment: But a simple question: i have allocated memory for username and password. Now with strdup i duplicate the memory. Have i to double free these pointers???

Comment: @polslinux Yes, you have to free stuff returned by `strdup`.